# Query Search need to allow Lower and Upper Case Characters

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I am looking to run this query and when I put a value in the Search box `B2` it will allow me to look up a name that is lower or uppercase. It works fine without the Where Lower statement. Any help will be great.

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:K;Sheet2!A:K;Sheet3:K;Sheet4!A:K;Sheet5!A:K;Sheet6T!A:K;Sheet7!A:K;Sheet8!A:K;Sheet9!A:K}, "WHERE LOWER(Col2) LIKE LOWER is not null 
    and Col2 ="""&B2&"""
  order by Col1", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `QUERY()`.

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:K;Sheet2!A:K;Sheet3!A:K;Sheet4!A:K;Sheet5!A:K;Sheet6T!A:K;Sheet7!A:K;Sheet8!A:K;Sheet9!A:K}, 
    "WHERE Col2 is not null and LOWER(Col2) ='" & LOWER(B2) & "' order by Col1", 1)
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked.